# Dishwasher fails to finish draining at beginning of cycle

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Kenwood KDW45X20. When I start the program the drain pump engages and any water is removed from the sump. But the drain pump continues for another 2 mins or so trying to pump "nothing" out of the sump. Then stops with an F2 error (drain failure).

I have tried filling the bottom of machine with water, turning onto the cycle, and draining into a bucket and it drains water just fine every time - all water sucked out - but it continues to pump nothing for 2 mins before stopping with error code. It is as if it does not know that it has finished the task and can move on.

I have removed and put back the drain pump, checked the impellor, checked the hoses - all clear.

** Edit - I'm ordering a new level switch to the sump and will update here once I know the result **

Comment: did you check the float sensor that checks the water level?

Comment: I'd assume (haven't delved into machine marts)  there must be such a float or level sensor, and I'd assume its stuck or broken, yeah.

Comment: I checked the float switch in the base of the machine. I think it could be the level switch which is integrated into the sump. I did a continuity check and it seemed OK but that was during a time when the fault was intermittent. I'm gonna replace it.